# PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql

Después de ejecutar este procedimiento almacenado, recibo este error:

```
create or replace procedure "delete-archive"
is 
val NUMBER;
begin
for i in (select * from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR'))
 where FILENAME like 'JDE%')
 loop
 UTL_FILE.FREMOVE ('DATA_PUMP_DIR', i.filename );
 end loop;
end;
```

Genera este error:

```
5/11      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/40      PL/SQL: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
8/5       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
8/40      PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid
```

¿Alguna ayuda o consejo?

Comment: Revisa que tu usuario tenga permisos de lectura y escritura sobre el directorio : `SELECT * 
  FROM all_tab_privs WHERE table_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';`

Comment: Ya revise y soluciones esa parte gracias!!, alguna ayuda con este error que es el principal 8/40      PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid

Comment: Creo que sigue siendo derivado del problema de los privilegios: el usuario dueño del procedimiento debe tener permisos de lectura/escritura sobre el directorio. Al no haber privilegios => no hay resultado => no hay tabla => no hay cursor => no hay variable `i`. Prueba tu código en un bloque anónimo.